# css: target a class which is inside a same class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am currently working on a Wordpress project. It has a 3 level menu.

`.submenu` has to be hidden until its on the same page. Now I have to hide `.submenu`, which is inside submeu.

How do I target this?

I have to target `#mainmenu > . submenu  > .submenu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly like that `#mainmenu .submenu .submenu`.

Comment: hahaha! thanks that worked. I tried it but I think it was cache. will accept answer after 10 mins. because i cant now.